# Running container test with environment variable

Tags: python-2.7, docker, environment-variables, python-unittest

I can log into my python container with

```
docker exec -it my_container bash
```

Once in I can change the environment variable and run the tests in a single command,

```
APP_ENV="test" python ./manage.py test
```

Additionally, I can run the tests without logging into the container using

```
docker exec -it my_container python ./manage.py test
```

but if I try to change the environment variable and run the tests in a single command, namely,

```
docker exec -it my_container APP_ENV="test" python ./manage.py test
```

I get an error:

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"APP_ENV=test\": executable file not found in $PATH"

How can I change the environment variable and run the tests in a single command without logging into the container first?

Comment: This seems like an odd way of interacting with your container...but in any case, you can use the `env` command: `docker exec -it my_container env APP_ENV="test" python ./manage.py test`

Comment: @larsks Perfect! If you want to put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [env](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) command:

```
docker exec -it my_container env APP_ENV="test" python ./manage.py test
```